# In the angular-ui-grid,how do I use rowSelectionChanged with vm instead of $scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I want to use:

```
gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged(vm, callBackFunction)
```

instead of:

```
gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope, callBackFunction)
```

When I do it causes an error.

Comment: What error? If you want answers you need to ask questions that can be answered.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the component scope to the gridAPI methods using `.call(vm, null).` So in your case it will be:

```
gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged.call(vm, null, callBackFunction)
```